# Глубина иерархического списка, заданного S-выражением

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lisp

Как вычислить глубину иерархического списка, заданного S-выражением, основываясь на анализе числа одновременно открытых левых скобок? Например, глубина списка (a(b(c)d)e) будет равна 2, (a(b(c.d)e)(k.f)m)– тоже двум. Впрочем, могу ошибаться и здесь.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиде максимальную глубину списка?

Comment: Текст однострочный или нет? Что может содержаться в списке, только символы или еще числа и строки? Коментарии могут быть? Вобщем раскройте проблему подробнее.

Comment: @Cerbo я думаю, тут важно знать, что такое s-выражение, для понимания вопроса. Вот статья https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Отлично, добавьте эту ссылку в вопрос, и дополните его как вас просили. Тогда велика вероятность что вопрос заново откроют и ответят.

Answer (score -1):

Найти максимум разницы между количеством открывающих и закрывающих скобок по всем подстрокам разной длины, начинающимся с начала.
Можно в цикле через `substr`, можно рекуррентно самому.